# 'Sneak' Extra Devices into Provisioning Profile for Beta

Tags: xcode, ios-provisioning

So I was snooping around in my provisioning profile and I found that the list of unique identifiers is stored in plain text. If I add more than 100 devices to this list will it work? Apple cuts you off at 100 if you do it through the website. Anyone have experience with this? Will it disable my app if I do that? If so any other ways around the Ad Hoc restrictions they impose

```
<key>ProvisionedDevices</key>
<array>
            <string>the number</string>
            <string>another number</string>
            <string>etc</string>

</array>
```

Comment: It probaly will not work, since allowed devices would be identified somehow in the certificate.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, no this will not work.  As you have seen while perusing your mobile provisioning profile, there is a great deal of information encoded in plain text in one of these profiles -- an App ID, Public Keys of Developer Certificates, Provisioned Device IDs, etc.  While there is nothing prohibiting you from adding or changing information in this plain-text section (it is after all a file on your machine) what will cause this to fail is the information encoded in the binary section of this file.

As you know, Apple requires that all App Store apps be signed by a developer this is to 1) provide a basis of 'developer identity' on the store and 2) ensure that the binary you upload to Apple isn't tampered with when being downloaded or used by customers.  This process leverages Public Key Infrastructure to verify the cryptographic signature generated by a developer is actually 'trusted' by the platform...essentially a mathematical method of ensuring that the contents of a file/app/message haven't been modified since being signed by the developer.

*Why is this an important distinction?*

This notion of 'trust' is the basis of security on the platform -- everything must be signed. From the bootloader all the way up to your app, each link in the chain must be signed by an authority that the device trusts...in this case Apple. If at any point the math doesn't work out then there is a security breach and that bit of code is not allowed to execute (NOTE: This does not necessarily hold true on Jailbroken devices, but that it a topic for an entirely different question).

Since you've indicated you've taken a look at your provisioning profile, you likely also saw some binary data mixed in with the plain-text data you've asked about.  This binary data is partially code signature and partially PKI data -- it ensures that the information contained in the plain-text section hasn't been...shall we say 'tweaked'...since the file was issued to you by Apple and is verified by Xcode and iOS. This circles back on a phrase that you might have heard thrown around a bit: 'Your security is as strong as the weakest link'.  In a hypothetical world where provisioning profiles weren't signed, some rogue individual could circumvent the iOS security architecture with a series of simple text edits and we would have a variety of ways in which to circumvent the App Store distribution mechanism and circumvent the 100-device limits imposed by the Certificates, Identities, and Profiles tool -- This hypothetical situation is not ideal from a platform security standpoint, and thus why we have code sign requirements in the first place.

I'd also be remiss to fail to acknowledge that this is typically an entry point to a discussion on the merits of 'open' vs 'closed' ecosystems.  Because it is well beyond the scope of this question and ventures into the minefield of impassioned opinions we won't dig into it...sorry to disappoint.

Apple put out a [whitepaper on iOS security](http://images.apple.com/iphone/business/docs/iOS_Security_Oct12.pdf), discussing the secure boot loader, code signature, and security architectures built into core iOS -- it is a great read for those curious about the publicly-presentable guts of iOS security.

In the interim, short of having a bunch of Jailbroken devices, the only legitimate way to get additional test device slots is to purchase a second iOS developer program and setup a second appID, second set of provisioning profiles, and by extension a second set of build configurations to be able to resign the app using a different set of provisioned devices.